# Explain the difference between contiguous allocation (memory held in a heap in the stack) vs. memory in a heap

Tags: java, allocation

Explain the difference between contiguous allocation (memory held in a heap in the stack) vs. memory in a heap.

I'm new at this and not entirely sure.

Comment: Have you done any research before posting?

Comment: What is it you're actually asking here?  I see two or three questions...none of which are directly related to the title of your question.

Comment: yes I've tried and was not able to find a clear direct answer Which is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't contiguous versus heap, but automatic versus heap.

Automatic storage is set up on entry to a block of code -- traditionally on entry to a function or method -- and discarded when that function returns, so its memory space on the stack can be reused by the next function call. That's how most local variables are handled. Obviously this isn't useful for anything which is intended to persist past the end of that function call.

In Java, objects are never allocated from automatic storage. Instead, they are allocated from the heap, on demands, when the `new` operation is performed. There are several reasons for this which, frankly, unless you're designing a programming language you don't really need to know about and it's too large a topic to cover here. The important thing is that since they were obtained from the heap, their lifetime is independent of the stack frame. Since Java is a garbage-collected language, their memory will be automatically recovered for reuse sometime after that last reference to them goes away -- again, the details are too large a topic to cover here, but basically you can trust that the GC comes through periodically to pick up the clothes we dropped on the floor and toss them into the laundry.

Comment: See also several of the answers under "related" at the right side of this page. And/or clarify what you're confused by.

Answer (score 1):

When we talk about memory or disc allocation, the word "contiguous" simply means "without any gaps".

- A single stack or heap memory allocation is always contiguous ... in every programming language runtime I've ever encountered where it makes sense to talk about allocations at all.
- A sequence of allocations is contiguous if there is no gap between the individual allocations.

This is orthogonal to stack versus heap.  Both stack allocations and heap allocations can be contiguous ... or non-contiguous.

---

Well ... not quite orthogonal.

If you are talking about strictly contiguous memory addresses (physical or virtual), a *typical* heap node consists of the area of memory that the application can use, plus a small node header.  So, if you look at the available memory for two consecutive heap nodes, there is a gap ... comprising the node header ... that prevents the two regions being used by the application as a single contiguous region.  (And you'd better not try 'cos if you overwrite the node header, bad things could happen.)

However, when we are talking about Java this is not relevant.  Java does not allow an application to join objects or arrays together.  (That would be a fundamental violation of runtime type safety.)  So the notional gap in the address ranges doesn't matter.  In the Java context, we would say that two objects are contiguous, ignoring the heap node / object header.

---

Besides, in Java you can't explicitly allocate things on the heap either.  In a classical JVM, only local variables comprising primitive types and references go on the stack.  There is no way to say "allocate this array on the stack".  (The JVM might do the latter under certain circumstances, but it is entirely transparent to the application, and certainly not something that you could make use of.)

Answer (score 1):

A stack frame only exists for the life of a method call, which means that memory is allocated to provide storage for all your local variables and method parameters that are used in some way that assist helping the method achieve its goals of whatever task it set out to achieve.

Examples of memory storage in a stack frame are temporary pointers that are used to keep track of an index position in an array which you are iterating through. Once the loop is finished, the stack frame would be popped off the stack, which means all the temporary memory allocated for the local variables and method parameters that existed are released back into the system.

The heap is different because it is where objects live, not "pointers" to objects.

When I was learning I found it hard to work out the difference between the two. 
The key point that helped me was that, a pointer to an object is kept in a stack frame, it has a little bit of temporary memory allocated that exists for the life time of the method call. Thus, you can only access an object when the method is in "scope".

The pointer contains a memory address that leads to the location of the object stored on the heap. This allows you to reference the object to change the objects state at a later time.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Person person = new Person("Steven", 30);
  }
```

When you run this program:

1. new keyword means java will allocate memory on the heap for the space required to store  the Person objects instance variables.

The important part to understand is, no memory is required to store an objects methods. When a method is called, a new stack frame is created which allocates temporary memory for the duration of the method call. Using the example above, a Person has 2 instance variables, a String name and int age. This means that the memory required for this Person object is the required memory to store a **reference** variable of type String (bit pattern of the memory address of a String object on the heap) and memory to hold the bit pattern of an int.

Lastly, the main method is a stack frame too, so when main finishes, you no longer have a reference to a Person object or access to any temporary variables that may have existed in main.

This is true for any method, if you have a method that creates an object but doesn't return the reference to that object, then you can never access the object and the java garbage collector comes along at a later time and cleans up all the objects on the heap that don't have references pointing to them.

If you are starting out, I highly recommend head first java. It is a great book IMO and covers these topics in easy to understand ways.